# How do I make apt-get install commands not display every package that is installing?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, gnome-terminal

When I install something on terminal, it often shows me a few things for status. For one, it shows download rate (which is fine). However, when I install something, it can display

```
Unpacking libgranite2:amd64 (0.3.0~r732+pkg64~ubuntu0.3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package slingshot-launcher.
Preparing to unpack .../slingshot-launcher_0.7.6.1+r421+pkg32~ubuntu0.3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slingshot-launcher (0.7.6.1+r421+pkg32~ubuntu0.3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package contractor.
Preparing to unpack .../contractor_0.3.1~r136+pkg22~ubuntu0.3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking contractor (0.3.1~r136+pkg22~ubuntu0.3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apport-hooks-elementary.
Preparing to unpack .../apport-hooks-elementary_0.1-0~35~saucy1_all.deb ...
Unpacking apport-hooks-elementary (0.1-0~35~saucy1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.40.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libgranite-common (0.3.0~r732+pkg64~ubuntu0.3.1) ...
Setting up libgranite2:amd64 (0.3.0~r732+pkg64~ubuntu0.3.1) ...
Setting up slingshot-launcher (0.7.6.1+r421+pkg32~ubuntu0.3.1) ...
Setting up contractor (0.3.1~r136+pkg22~ubuntu0.3.1) ...
Setting up apport-hooks-elementary (0.1-0~35~saucy1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ..
```

I would rather that not show up. I only want to see download rate, not all that other stuff. How do I do this?

EDIT: I would also like the jargon to be stored somwehre else if something goes wrong, or for the jargon to just be expanable on terminal.

Comment: If something goes wrong, you're going to need this output.

Comment: @saiarcot895 edited question

Comment: If you redirect the output you will miss the prompt to continue and apt-get will hang there waiting for you to respond Y/n.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, try Ubuntu Software Center!

Comment: Well, not all packages are installable through software center.

Comment: Correct, but there are several that are.

Comment: Well I already install what I can with software center, I'm just looking for a solution for the packages that must be installed from terminal

Answer (score 0):

<strike>sudo apt-get install  &> installoutput.txt redirects it to a file. The download rate is difficult, you can redirect all of it, or none.</strike>

As ElderGeek pointed out, this doesn't work.

As EcarterYoung pointed out, this one does work?:

`sudo apt-get install <package> --assume-yes &> installoutput.txt` redirects it to a file.

Comment: Tim will the problem that elder geek pointed out apply for your solution?

Comment: No, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Apt Man Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man8/apt-get.8.html), and add -d, short for --download-only.  For this to work, you'd have to run apt twice(the first pass will do --download-only, and the second pass will install/upgrade etc) To run in one command use the [&&(And)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of) operator .  For Elder Geek's/Tim's solution to work add --assume-yes

Comment: How does this hide the output?

Comment: The OP only wants to see the download rate.  This is as close as we can get.

Comment: You should probably state that in your answer then.

Comment: Why, question readers who actually read the question will see Download only, I did, but I'll edit it